# Remove multiple column labels from Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to remove the column labels from a query and I've tried the following two ways but still getting error. What's the best way to do this?

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!2:115, "SELECT C, label(AVG(D),''), label(AVG(E),''), label(AVG(F),''), label(AVG(G),''), label(AVG(H),''), label(AVG(I),''), label(AVG(J),''), label(AVG(K),''), label(AVG(L),'') WHERE C IS NOT NULL GROUP BY C ORDER BY C", 0)

=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!2:115,"SELECT C,AVG(D),AVG(E),AVG(F),AVG(G),AVG(H),AVG(I),AVG(J),AVG(K),AVG(L) WHERE C IS NOT NULL GROUP BY C ORDER BY C label(D),label(E),label(F),label(G),label(H),label(I),label(J),label(K),label(L) ",0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to write `label` once, followed by the columns you want to label and the label you want to give them.

```
=QUERY(data,"... label A '', B '', C''...")
```

Comment: that makes a lot more sense, but now it's saying "LABEL_COL_NOT_IN_SELECT: 'D', oh wait, maybe I should add AVG(D)?

Comment: Yup that was it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try shorter:

```
=QUERY(QUERY('Form Responses 1'!2:115, 
 "SELECT C,AVG(D),AVG(E),AVG(F),AVG(G),AVG(H),AVG(I),AVG(J),AVG(K),AVG(L) 
  WHERE C IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY C 
  ORDER BY C"), "offset 1", )
```